# R subset data frame where date is less than a variable date

Tags: r, date, subset, as.date

I am trying to select a subset of a data frame where the date needs to be less than a (calculated/variable) date.

The following code throws an error:

```
loanFrame_excluding_young <- loanFrame[loanFrame$LoanEffective < AddMonths(as.Date("2015-11-11"),-loanFrame$TermMonths),]
Error in seq.Date(X[[i]], ...) : 'by' must be of length 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give a reproductable example. Edit your question.

Comment: If you're unsure how, here's how to create a [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's a good point! Expect AddMonths by the next version of DescTools (0.99.16) to recycle all of its arguments.

Comment: AddMonths does now (0.99.17) recyle its arguments:

library(DescTools)
AddMonths(as.Date("2015-11-11"), -c(1,3,5,7))
[1] "2015-10-11" "2015-08-11" "2015-06-11" "2015-04-11"

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the DescTools::AddMonths function. in AddMonths(x, n, ceiling = TRUE) the n can only be a single number, not a vector.

Using the following code does work using the %m-% function of lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)

loanFrame <- data.frame(TermMonths = c(1,3,5,7), 
                        LoanEffective = as.Date(c("2015-09-15", "2015-08-05", "2015-10-01", "2015-06-25")))

loanFrame_excluding_young <- loanFrame[loanFrame$LoanEffective < as.Date("2015-11-11") %m-% months(loanFrame$TermMonths),]

loanFrame_excluding_young

  TermMonths LoanEffective
1          1    2015-09-15
2          3    2015-08-05
```